# expl3: What is the difference between `:V` and `:x` in practice?

Tags: expl3

When a command `\...:n` requires to receive to value of the argument, one can use its `:V` variant. But before I learned about `:V`, I've always been using `:x` for making the argument fully expanded, which usually results in the value. It is not quite clear to me which should be used in practice, and I've been randomly choosing from these two.

In the following example, they are produce the same result. But without `\number`, only the `:V` version works. Does this mean that the `:V` version would usually be better for this propose?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_mytest:n { #1 }

\exp_args:NV \mymodule_mytest:n { \number \year }

\exp_args:Nx \mymodule_mytest:n { \number \year }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `V`-type argument should be a single token, the name of a variable. At the TeX level, these can be implemented as either macros or registers - to access the latter, at the TeX level one needs `\the` or `\number` (where appropriate). This is all wrapped up inside some clever code such that `V`-type arguments 'just work'

```latex
\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_int
```

for example will set the `tl` (a macro) to the value of the `int` (a register).

Expanding to the value is itself expandable, and will only carry out one level of expansion for token lists. Thus

```latex
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { bong }
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:V \l_tmpb_tl }
```

will result in `\g_tmpa_tl` containing `\l_tmpa_tl`, not `bong`.

In contrast, `x`-type expansion is *non-expandable*, taking a *balanced text* argument and exhaustively expanding whatever is inside it. This means that variables inside an `x`-type argument need appropriate accessors.

```latex
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
```

and that we will get the final, unexpandable, tokens if applies to a `tl`, thus

```latex
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { bong }
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpb_tl }
```

means that `\g_tmpa_tl` contains `bong`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Ooops, yes, I meant to `x`-type that last step :) Sorted now

Comment: By "`x`-type expansion is non-expandable" do you mean that functions one of whose parameter specifiers is `x` are non-expandable?

Comment: @EvanAad That's correct.

Comment: What about `f`-type expansion? Is it too non-expandable?

Comment: @EvanAad `f`-type expansion is expandable

Answer (score 9):

#### Added January 2023

The question is about `x`-expansion, but nowadays `e`-expansion is more convenient. Just replace `x` with `e` below.

#### Answer

The convention for letters in function signatures (the part after the colon) is that uppercase letters denote single token arguments (no braces) and lowercase letters denote braced arguments. Exception: `T` and `F` are used in conditionals and denote braced arguments; they always come last in function names defined with `\prg_new_(protected_)conditional:Nnn`.

Of course, `expl3` cannot change TeX's syntax rules, so adding braces around an argument that doesn't require them results in simply stripping them; but, please, *don't* exploit this fact. Your code will be more readable if

- you *always* avoid braces around `N` or `V` type arguments;
- you *always* use braces around all other argument types.

Now, is there any difference between `V` and `x`? Yes, much like comparing  fish and trees. For several reasons:

1. a `V` argument is a *single* token;
2. an `x` argument can consist of several tokens (even zero);
3. a `V` argument must be a variable of type `tl`, `clist`, `str` or any type corresponding to registers, that is, `int`, `dim`, `skip` or `muskip`.
4. an `x` argument can be pretty much anything;
5. a `V` argument will return the variable's content as a braced `n` argument;
6. an `x` argument is a braced argument.

Apart from the fact that `\number` should not be used in `expl3` code, your attempt

```
\exp_args:NV \mymodule_mytest:n { \number \year }
```

produces `2022` by pure chance. And you'd never even try it if you followed the conventions stated above about braces: it would be like trying `\mbox\number\year` which obviously cannot work. Or `\mbox\bgroup xyz\egroup` that *seems* to work, but actually doesn't and produces no error message by pure chance.

Let's assume you want to pass the value of `\c_sys_year_int` (aka `\year`) to `\my_command:n` which in turn will extract the first digit; you will do

```
\cs_new:Nn \jinwen_extract_msd:n
 {
  \tl_head:n { #1 }
 }
```

(`msd` stands for “most significant digit”). Then you can achieve your result in three ways:

```
\exp_args:NV \jinwen_extract_msd:n \c_sys_year_int
\exp_args:Ne \jinwen_extract_msd:n { \int_use:N \c_sys_year_int }
\exp_args:Nx \jinwen_extract_msd:n { \int_use:N \c_sys_year_int }
```

The last one is the least recommended, because it is *not* expandable. The middle one is expandable like the top one, but it's uselessly complicated and inefficient.

However, you should not use `\exp_args:NV`, generally speaking. Unless it's for a one shot application, you should better define a variant:

```
\cs_new:Nn \jinwen_extract_msd:n
 {
  \tl_head:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jinwen_extract_msd:n { V }
```

and you will be able to simply call

```
\jinwen_extract_msd:V \c_sys_year_int
```

which is even clearer than the three token construction above, isn't it?

Comment: Remark: uppercase `T` and `F` are braced arguments.

Comment: @L.J.R. Yes, that's important.

Comment: You wrote: "a `V` argument must be a variable of type `tl`, `int`, `fp` or `clist`". I haven't seen this mentioned in [The expl3 package and LATEX3 programming](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) doc. Is this an actual requirement, or your opinion regarding how the `V` argument ought to be used?

Comment: I've just noticed there's a list on p. 4 of [The LaTeX3 Interfaces](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) doc detailing the expandable variable types. They are: `clist`, `dim`, `fp`, `int`, `muskip`, `seq`, `skip`, `str`, and `tl`. All other variable types, it appears, are incompatible with the `V` function parameter specifier.