# Difference between the V function parameter specifier and the o specifier in LaTeX3 programming

Tags: expl3, latex3, programming

In LaTeX3 programming, how does the `V` function parameter specifier differ from the `o` specifier? How is the `o` specifier meant to be used in contrast to the `V` specifier?

---

A related question: [V vs. x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633224/21685)

Comment: See also: [expl3 - Can we safely use o expansion when V expansion is not available? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635390/can-we-safely-use-o-expansion-when-v-expansion-is-not-available)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `o`-specifier is 'lower-level' and does exactly one expansion of the argument: `\foo:o {...}` is equivalent to `\expandafter \foo:n \expandafter {...}`. In contrast, `V`-type expansion provides the *value* of a variable, which may be either a `tl`/`clist` (stored as a macro) or an `int`/`dim`/`skip` (stored as a register). To deal with the latter, `V`-type expansion inserts the required `\the` to yield the value. Thus `o`-type expansion is only equivalent to `V`-type where you know that the value to expand is a macro. One may use `o`-type expansion for cases where `V`-type does not apply, e.g.

```latex
\foo:n { \use_none:n <some tokens> }
```

Notice that the `o`-type takes a *balanced text* argument (zero or more tokens in braces), whereas the `V`-type takes a single token. This is quite different in semantics.

Comment: Also while `o` accepts arbitrarily many tokens one should highlight that `V` only works with single token input.

Answer (score 6):

`o` means “expand one level”.

`V` means “get the value of”.

While this *might* produce the same result for `tl` or `clist` variables, this isn't the case with other variables.

Let's try a toy problem, namely extracting the most significant digit from the integer stored in any `int` variable or given explicitly.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\msd}{sm}
 {% \msd* takes a variable
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \aad_msd:V #2
    }
    {
     \aad_msd:n { #2 }
    }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \aad_msd:n
 {
  \__aad_msd:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aad_msd:n { V,o }

\cs_new:Npn \__aad_msd:w #1 #2 \q_stop { #1 }

\int_new:N \l_aad_test_a_int
\int_set:Nn \l_aad_test_a_int { 1234 }
\int_const:Nn \c_aad_test_b_int {4321}

\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \msd{4321} } \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \msd*{\l_aad_test_a_int} } \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \msd*{\c_aad_test_b_int} } \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you try this, you get

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=4.
> \l_tmpa_tl=1.
> \l_tmpa_tl=4.
```

Now replace `\aad_msd:V #2` with `\aad_msd:o { #2 }` and you'll get

```
> \l_tmpa_tl=4.
> \l_tmpa_tl=\l_aad_test_a_int .
> \l_tmpa_tl=\c_aad_test_b_int .
```

Do you see what happens? Integer variables aren't expandable, so `:o` does nothing to them. The same with all variables that correspond to registers: `dim`, `skip`, `muskip`.